# VPN Split Tunneling with VM safer?

Tags: privacy, vpn, virtualization

I want to privately surf in a Virtual machine. I am questioning if it would be better/more private to use the Split Tunneling feature of my VPN Program (on the Host installed) and only allow my VM to use the VPN while the Host uses my normal connection.

Are there any risks of doing so or is it really safer?

btw. I trust my VPN Provider to have no logs or share any information with a 3rd party, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Even if you trust your VPN to not keep logs (a foolish assumption), the fact is that its ISP _does_ keep logs, and its ISP has effectively the same capabilities as the VPN for traffic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not an issue of logging or privacy of the VPN provider as much as it is your general browsing traffic, if not theoretically filtered by a content filter as it could be if all traffic was tunneled through the VPN's internet access, is now subject to allowing you to get to potentially harmful sites (malware, porn, gambling, etc.) which could then traverse the tunnel to infect those remote machines.  Depending on which compliances you may be subject to (IRS, HIPAA, PCI, etc.), you may not be able to enable split-tunnel without being in violation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of running the VPN on the host machine, and then using the VM is a better way. Whonix was built around this idea. Qubes OS also does the same thing. The host OS runs the VPN client, then the VM does not manage the VPN. This idea is why some choose to deploy a VPN on their router, besides other reasons.

*(HostOS(Virtualised OS))---(VPN)---(X)*  is safer if you are concerned about the virtualised OS being compromised at a high level, in which the VPN could be disabled. Given this, I would advise having kill switches, in the event the connection to the VPN fails your firework disabled all ingress and egress traffic, or simply disable all networking interfaces.